# How to print counts based on two variables found in two columns including the name of the variables from a big datafile?

Tags: excel, bash, count

I have a data file containing 1000+ rows of data. Please see the format of the datafile below.

```
Gene Name   Gene ID Transcription Factor Name   Transcription Factor ID
AT3G01175   34269   ZHD6    MA1330.1
AT3G01175   34269   ZHD6    MA1330.1
AT3G01175   34269   ZHD6    MA1330.1
AT3G01175   34269   ZHD6    MA1330.1
AT2G436200  34293   ARF4    MA1697.1
AT2G436200  34293   WRKY40  MA1085.2
AT2G436200  34293   WRKY40  MA1085.2
AT2G436200  34293   WRKY40  MA1085.2
AT2G436200  34293   NAC016  MA2005.1
AT2G436200  34293   NAC016  MA2005.1
AT2G436200  34293   NAC016  MA2005.1
AT2G436200  34293   AHL12   MA0932.1
AT2G436200  34293   AHL12   MA0932.1
```

I want to get an output based on column1 and 3.
As an example

```
Gene Name   Transcription Factor Name   Count
AT3G01175   ZHD6    4
```

I was trying to use `countifs` for the purpose (excel). However, it was not successful.
I really appreciate it if you can help me in this regard. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You used the csv tag, but there is no comma in your file.

Comment: Apologies. I deleted the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AWK, assuming you want a csv file as output:

```
BEGIN{
    FS = " "
}
{
    if (NR != 1) {
        if (genes[$1"-"$3] == "") {
            genes[$1"-"$3] = 1
        } else {
            genes[$1"-"$3] = genes[$1"-"$3] + 1
        }
    }
}

END {
    print "Gene Name,Transition Factor Name,Count"
    for (key in genes) {
        split(key, values, "-")
        print values[1] "," values[2] "," genes[key]
    }
}
```

---

```
$ awk -f count.awk data 
Gene Name,Transition Factor Name,Count
AT2G436200,NAC016,3
AT2G436200,AHL12,2
AT3G01175,ZHD6,4
AT2G436200,WRKY40,3
AT2G436200,ARF4,1
```

If you want three spaces as a delimiter as in your example, just change the print in the `END` block.