# How to transpose a column of a dataset while matching another column containing unequal number of values?

Tags: excel, bash, transpose

I have a subset of data  that was created using the help provided by /u/Itération-122442 from my original dataset using `awk` function. [Link to the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421072/how-to-print-counts-based-on-two-variables-found-in-two-columns-including-the-na)

```
Gene Name   Transcription_Factor_Name   Count
AT1G02190   AHL20   4
AT1G04445   AHL20   14
AT1G04600   AHL20   5
AT1G09080   AHL20   8
AT1G09932   AHL20   3
AT1G11300   AHL20   2
AT1G19250   AHL20   1
AT1G02190   AHL25   2
AT1G04445   AHL25   20
AT1G04600   AHL25   5
AT1G09080   AHL25   9
AT1G09932   AHL25   5
AT1G11300   AHL25   1
AT1G19250   AHL25   3
AT1G23840   AHL25   5
```

Now I want to convert the dataset to its final form as follows

```
Gene Name   AHL20   AHL25
AT1G02190   4   2
AT1G04445   14  20
AT1G04600   5   5
AT1G09080   8   9
AT1G09932   3   5
AT1G11300   2   1
AT1G19250   1   3
AT1G23840   0   5
```

Things get very complex since the values that come under Gene Name are not the same for all because Transcription factors (column 2) can be present or absent from some Genes (gene names). Updated: Please see the last entry (AT1G23840) has no entry under AHL20 so it needs to be added as 0,
I really appreciate it if someone can help me to get this sorted out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: A pivot table should be able to handle this.

Comment: "_Things get very complex since the values that come under Gene Name are not the same for all because Transcription factors (column 2) can be present or absent from some Genes (gene names)._": please edit your question to provide an example of this case and to show what output you expect then.

Comment: Updated the post based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input and output field separators are tabs, and your data set fits in memory, you could try this GNU `awk` script:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
NR > 1 { c[$1][$2] += $3; t[$2] }
END {
  printf("Gene Name")
  for(a in t) printf("%s%s", OFS, a)
  printf("\n")
  for(g in c) {
    printf("%s", g)
    for(a in t) printf("%s%d", OFS, c[g][a] + 0)
    printf("\n")
  }
}' foo.tsv
Gene Name        AHL20    AHL25
AT1G23840        0        5
AT1G11300        2        1
AT1G04445        14       20
AT1G04600        5        5
AT1G19250        1        3
AT1G09080        8        9
AT1G02190        4        2
AT1G09932        3        5
```

Comment: I tried it and getting the following error ```awk: cmd. line:3: Unexpected token```

Comment: What is your version of awk? Are you sure your input field separator is a tab?